# Fazer um replace case insensitive em ASP Clássico (VBScript)

Tags: javascript, asp, vbscript

Tenho a string abaixo:

```
texto = "Meu texto"
```

Gostaria de fazer um replace na palavra "Meu" e retornar ela em negrito. O resultado ficaria assim:

**Meu** texto

Porém, o replace é case sensitive, ou seja, se eu usar `replace(texto,"meu","<b>meu</b>")` não acontece nada por causa do 'M' maiúsculo.

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer um replace em ASP clássico com VBScript ignorando letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas? Ou é mais fácil fazer isso em JavaScript ou jQuery?

> Obs.: eu poderia converter tudo para minúsculas, mas quero que o retorno mantenha as letras maiúsculas da string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe do `Replace` do `ASP VBScript` é a seguinte:

> `Replace(string,find,replacewith[,start[,count[,compare]]])`

[onde o último parâmetro `compare` deve ser colocado **1** que é a ***pesquisa por texto***](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp) ([Explicação: 1 = vbTextCompare comparação da string de forma Textual. (Insensitive)](http://adrianorosa.com/blog/asp/funcao-replace-do-asp.html)) [sendo que a padrão está **0** que é a ***pesquisa binária***](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp), por isso que a alteração não é feita.

***Exemplo:***

```
<%

    Dim texto
    texto = "Meu texto"
    
    Response.Write ( replace(texto,"meu","<b>Meu</b>", 1, -1, 1) )
    Response.Write ( "<br />")
    Response.Write ( replace(texto,"mEu","<b>Meu</b>", 1, -1, 1) )
    Response.Write ( "<br />")
    Response.Write ( replace(texto,"meU","<b>Meu</b>", 1, -1, 1) )
    Response.Write ( "<br />")
    Response.Write ( replace(texto,"MEU","<b>Meu</b>", 1, -1, 1) )
    Response.Write ( "<br />")    

%>
```

***Saída:***

> **Meu** texto
>
> **Meu** texto
>
> **Meu** texto
>
> **Meu** texto

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [VBScript Replace Function](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp)
- [Função Replace do Asp](http://adrianorosa.com/blog/asp/funcao-replace-do-asp.html)

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou como eu gostaria.